# Dynamic binding multi queue to one handler

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Is it possible to bind many queues to exactly one event handler ? The key thing is that these queues will be added (binded) dynamically, first one, next two and so on.  I would like to have only one event handler.

Maybe code-based created queue which is backed by `n` other existing queues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [Spring AMPQ](http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/), then you should be familiar with the `ListenerContainer` abstraction. So, you configure your single listener (`handler` in your terms) and let the container to manage queues and other connection and lifecycle options.

You can find all the required options in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#containerAttributes). 
Also see  [Listener Container Queues](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#listener-queues):

> See methods `addQueues`, `addQueueNames`, `removeQueues` and `removeQueueNames`

More info in the: [Dynamically add new queues, bindings and exchanges as beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241880/dynamically-add-new-queues-bindings-and-exchanges-as-beans)

Comment: One  thing is unclear: You suggest `addQueues`, however later you give link in which we manually modify spring's context: `context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("foo", new Queue("foo"));` What's go on ?

Comment: Nothing. Just a complement. This story is about how to modify container. That one how to add queues for management in the application context.

Comment: So I can use one of them ?

Comment: No, for your use-case you have to use my answer. If you need administration of new queues, you have to register them as beans. The container works pretty well just with queue names.

Comment: Ok, so I must register queues as beans. `context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("foo", new Queue("foo"))` and then call `addQueues`? Keep in mind that I use spring-boot.

Comment: The Spring Boot subject unrelated. If you have queues on the Broker already, you need only their names to subscribe at runtime. Otherwise yes, you have to register them as beans first of all and call `admin.initialize()`.

Comment: I have always queues on broker created. I only would like to subscribe queues (dynamically, at runtime). Listener is written also.

Comment: So, you don't need that `registerSingleton()` hack. You only need `addQueueNames()`. That's it

Comment: I need `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` to call `addQueueNames`. I can do it configure bean manually. However, there is no bean automatically created that I may inject with `@Autowired` ?